# In java how to get substring from a string till a character c?

Tags: java

I have a string (which is basically a file name following a naming convention) `abc.def.ghi`

I would like to extract the substring before the first `.` (ie a dot)

In java doc api, I can't seem to find a method in String which does that.
Am I missing something? How to do it?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

look at `String.indexOf` and `String.substring`.

Make sure you check for -1 for `indexOf`.

Answer (score 157):

The accepted answer is correct but it doesn't tell you how to use it. This is how you use indexOf and substring functions together.

```
String filename = "abc.def.ghi";     // full file name
int iend = filename.indexOf("."); //this finds the first occurrence of "." 
//in string thus giving you the index of where it is in the string

// Now iend can be -1, if lets say the string had no "." at all in it i.e. no "." is found. 
//So check and account for it.

String subString;
if (iend != -1) 
{
    subString= filename.substring(0 , iend); //this will give abc
}
```

Comment: This is invalid code because you can't put a variable declaration in the body of an If Statement without braces.

Comment: @Clashoft the braces are implied here.

Answer (score 108):

You can just [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the string..

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Note that java.lang.String.split uses delimiter's regular expression value.
Basically like this...

```
String filename = "abc.def.ghi";     // full file name
String[] parts = filename.split("\\."); // String array, each element is text between dots

String beforeFirstDot = parts[0];    // Text before the first dot
```

Of course, this is split into multiple lines for clairity. It could be written as

```
String beforeFirstDot = filename.split("\\.")[0];
```

Answer (score 93):

If your project already uses [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), StringUtils provide a nice method for this purpose:

```
String filename = "abc.def.ghi";

String start = StringUtils.substringBefore(filename, "."); // returns "abc"
```

see javadoc [[2.6]](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) [[3.1]](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 13):

or you may try something like

`"abc.def.ghi".substring(0,"abc.def.ghi".indexOf(c)-1);`

Comment: will crash of 'c' is not in the string as indexOf will return -1

Comment: @Umer Hayat What if the filename is `def.hij.klm`? How would your code work then? (Your code only works for this one example - you might as well write a function that returns `"abc"` - it would work just as well)

Comment: @Bohemian:I know there are boundary cases and checks missing. It was a specific a answer to to the specific question and idea was to give the general idea through an example :).

Comment: @TofuBeer: Reading question title, i think its a 'c' specific question.

Comment: Read the body of the question "I would like to extract the substring before the first . (ie a dot)".  I read the c in the title as a variable character, in the context of the body 'c' is '.'.

Comment: @TofuBeer: Ok, fine there is a confusion earlier "(ie a dot)" wasn't there in actual post. I think and hope my answer gives a general idea to solve this kin of problem.

Comment: I would go with:
int ix = inString.indexOf('.');
if (ix > -1) inString = inString.substring(0, ix);

I do not know why Umer suggested subtracting 1. The second argument of substring is up to but excluding anyway.

Answer (score 5):

How about using regex?

```
String firstWord = filename.replaceAll("\\..*","")
```

This replaces everything from the first dot to the end with "" (ie it clears it, leaving you with what you want)

Here's a test:

```
System.out.println("abc.def.hij".replaceAll("\\..*", "");
```

Output:

```
abc
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried something like this,

```
String str = "abc.def.ghi";
String strBeforeFirstDot = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.'));
// strBeforeFirstDot = "abc"
```

I tried for my example, to extract all char before @ sign in email to extract and provide a username.

Comment: I can't believe how much code some have answered with when this is all you need to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, this is undoubtedly the correct answer I believe. Anything else is less direct if not way overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 2):

In java.lang.String you get some methods like indexOf(): which returns you first index of a char/string.
and lstIndexOf: which returns you the last index of String/char

From Java Doc:

```
  public int indexOf(int ch)
  public int indexOf(String str)
```

Returns the index within this string of the **first occurrence** of the specified character.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void getStrings() {
    String params = "abc.def.ghi";
    String s1, s2, s3;
    s1 = params.substring(0, params.indexOf("."));
    params = params.substring(params.indexOf(".") + 1);
    s2 = params.substring(0, params.indexOf("."));
    params = params.substring(params.indexOf(".") + 1, params.length());
    s3 = params;
}
```

**the solution**

> s1="abc"
> s2="def"
> s3="ghi"

IF you have *more than* 3 String , so then it will look **exactly like s2**

Answer (score 1):

Here is code which returns a substring from a `String` until any of a given list of characters:

```
/**
 * Return a substring of the given original string until the first appearance
 * of any of the given characters.
 * <p>
 * e.g. Original "ab&cd-ef&gh"
 * 1. Separators {'&', '-'}
 * Result: "ab"
 * 2. Separators {'~', '-'}
 * Result: "ab&cd"
 * 3. Separators {'~', '='}
 * Result: "ab&cd-ef&gh"
 *
 * @param original   the original string
 * @param characters the separators until the substring to be considered
 * @return the substring or the original string of no separator exists
 */
public static String substringFirstOf(String original, List<Character> characters) {
    return characters.stream()
            .map(original::indexOf)
            .filter(min -> min > 0)
            .reduce(Integer::min)
            .map(position -> original.substring(0, position))
            .orElse(original);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
public static String getCorporateID(String fileName) {

    String corporateId = null;

    try {
        corporateId = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf("_"));
        // System.out.println(new Date() + ": " + "Corporate:
        // "+corporateId);
        return corporateId;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        corporateId = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return corporateId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private String getTextBefore(final String wholeString, String before){
   final int indexOf = wholeString.indexOf(before); 
   if(indexOf != -1){
       return wholeString.substring(0, indexOf);
   }
   return wholeString;
}
```