# Best way in Java to find the first part of a string excluding certain characters

Tags: java, string, indexof, replaceall

What's the best way in Java to find the first part of a string excluding certain characters. For info, the only common element is the first [. The numbers after that, before the next ] are of variable length.

Example input strings:

```
john[43] was
Dave[0] had
Sally[241] used
```

Required output strings:

```
john
Dave
Sally
```

Comment: So you just need characters before "[" ?

Comment: Just keep grabbing characters until you reach a bracket? It's not clear what the difficulty is here.

Comment: Regular expressions can do this for you pretty easily.

Comment: Find index position of [ , then substring the input string from 0th index to the found index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In java how to get substring from a string till a character c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683448/in-java-how-to-get-substring-from-a-string-till-a-character-c)

Comment: Yes, just the characters before the "[".

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of your delimeter character and take a substring from 0th index to that index.

```
String s = "John[1234]sadf";
System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("[")));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above but had to add + 1 at the end...("[") +1); the input I'm using it on didn't like it for some reason. I then currently remove the "[" with:
Name = Name.replaceAll("\\[", "");
I'll keep trying :)

Comment: Can I see your input?

Comment: It's from a chat stream, it's probably a null causing it tbh. Trying to review now.

Answer (score 0):

the following is a cheeky way of doing it, the split will however return an array.

```
String firstPart= inputString.split("[")[0];
```

another way would be to use substrings

```
int index = inputString.indexOf("[");
```

then use substring with that index to create a string for everything before that.

Comment: Heisenberg's answer covers the indexOf method, however i will leave my answer here as it does include the split method (granted it is inferior but may be useful for future reference)

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming it is possible for you to have text before `john[43] was`, maybe something like `as soon as john[43] was`.

Using regex you can create a list of Strings that would look like this:

```
 List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z])*\[\d*\]")
    .matcher(yourInputStringHere);
 while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
 }
```

- john[43]
- Dave[0]
- Sally[241]

This ensures no extra characters or whitespace are selected from the beginning of the input.

Then iterating through you could do something with them e.g.

```
for (String s: allMatches){
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("[")));
}
```