# Am I overcomplicating a simple solution in Java?

Tags: java

For my Java homework I need to create a script that returns the first word within a string, and, as a part two, I need to also return the second word. I'm currently working on the first part, and I think I'm close, but I'm also wondering if I am over complicating my code a bit.

```
public static void statements(){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    char [] sentenceArray;
    String userSentence;
    char sentenceResult;
    System.out.print("Enter a complete sentence: ");
    userSentence = userInput.nextLine();
    for(int x = 0; x < userSentence.length(); x++){
        sentenceResult = userSentence.charAt(x);
        sentenceArray = new char[userSentence.length()];
        sentenceArray[x] = sentenceResult;
        if(sentenceArray[x] != ' '){
            System.out.print(sentenceArray[x]);
            //break; This stops the code at the first letter due to != ' '
        }
    }
}
```

I think I've nearly got it. All I need to get working, for the moment, is the for loop to exit once it recognizes there is a space, but it prints out the entire message regardless. I'm just curious if this can be done a little simpler, as well as maybe a hint of what I could do instead, or how to finish.

Edit: I was able to get the assignment completed by using the split method. This is what it now looks like

```
    public static void statements(){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userSentence;
    System.out.print("Enter a complete sentence: ");
    userSentence = userInput.nextLine();
    String [] sentenceArray = userSentence.split(" ");
    System.out.println(sentenceArray[0]);
    System.out.println(sentenceArray[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Scanner.next()`?

Comment: Scanner works best for this. You can just pass a string to the constructor and do read next. The next best option is to split the input on whitespace `\s+`.

Comment: Not sure what the requirements are (you did not mention any), but if you can use library functions please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7683463/1566187

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In java how to get substring from a string till a character c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683448/in-java-how-to-get-substring-from-a-string-till-a-character-c)

Comment: For start you are creating your array for every char in your loop. Move `sentenceArray = new char[userSentence.length()];` to outside of the loop, I think only this will help you figure out what to do next...

Comment: One lesson you should learn as a student is to separate IO from your methods that do things.  Don't prompt a user for a sentence and also do the rest of the work; better to ask for it in a driver main and pass it into the method.  This is an easy problem, but not the way you're written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is your homework, I would feel bad to give you code and resolve it for you.

Seems like you really overcomplicated that, and you are aware, so it's good sign.

> I need to create a script that returns the first word within a string,
>   and, as a part two, I need to also return the second word

So, you have a `String` object, then check yourself the **[methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)** of that class.

It is possible to solve it in 2 lines of code, but:

1. you must be aware of one special method of String class, the most useful will be one that could somehow `split` the string for you
2. you need to have some knowledge about [java regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) - words are separated by `space`
3. after you split the `string`, you should get an array, accessing `first` and `second` element by `index` of an array will be sufficient

Comment: This helped. I searched through the methods and, as you mentioned, used split. I had no idea about it, and it did exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you are overthinking it.  Why not read in the whole line and split the string by whitespaces?  This isn't a complete solution, just a suggestion for how you can get the words.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter a complete sentence: ");
    try {
        String userSentence = reader.readLine();
        String[] words = userSentence.split(" ");
        System.out.println(words[0]);
        System.out.println(words[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: that would not work if words would be separated by more than one space character, so regexp `\\s+` would be better in `split` method

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.  Why not return *all* the words?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Add something descriptive here.
 * User: MDUFFY
 * Date: 8/31/2017
 * Time: 4:58 PM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989774/am-i-over-complicating-a-simple-solution
 */
public class WordSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Sentence: %s", arg));
            List<String> words = getWords(arg);
            System.out.println(String.format("# words : %d", words.size()));
            System.out.println(String.format("words   : %s", words));
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getWords(String sentence) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        if ((sentence != null) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(sentence.trim())) {
            sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[.!?\\-,]", "");
            String [] tokens = sentence.split("\\s+");
            words = Arrays.asList(tokens);
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

When I run it with this input on the command line:

```
"The quick, agile, beautiful fox jumped over the lazy, fat, slow dog!"
```

Here's the result I get:

```
Sentence: The quick, agile, beautiful fox jumped over the lazy, fat, slow dog!
# words : 12
words   : [The, quick, agile, beautiful, fox, jumped, over, the, lazy, fat, slow, dog]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Try to replace the list with array. he probably dind't learn it yet.

Comment: It stays. A stretch goal; easy to figure out.